# Async Await firestore user id

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have a set of firestore user id in an array object. How can i loop
over the array of userid and get each user username from firestore database. How can i achieve this using async await Java Script ES8

const array =["id1","id2"]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work.

```
const array=["id1","id2",...]//array of ids 
async function fetchData(){
  array.map(id=>{
    await fetch(<call to database using the id).then(res=>{//OK})
      .catch(err=> {not ok})
  })
}
```

Async await are a cleaner way to work with asynchronous functions like this.

Comment: This will not compile because you're using await inside a function that's not async (the function you're passing to `map` as a lambda).

Comment: @Thakur karthik how do you suppose we do this then? And also wouldn’t we have to return a promise after each Firestore database call else the data will never resolve

Answer (score 0):

You can use async/await in loop as below.

```
const array=["id1","id2",...]


fetchData = () => {
  array.forEach(async (id) => {
    try {
      await res = fetch(id)
      // Do something with your res 
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  })
}
```